# jQuery button click only every 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having troubles with some jQuery code when I click a button very quickly.  So to solve this I need to only allow users to click a button every 2 seconds or so.  How can I make a button only clickable every 2 seconds (or whatever time I choose)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're using `<button>` or `<input>`,

```
$('#yourButton').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.prop('disabled',true);
    window.setTimeout(function(){ 
        btn.prop('disabled',false);
    },2000);
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9sZeL/1/)

The `2000` is the length of time before the button is re-enabled, in milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

Have the "click" handler add a class ("clicked" maybe) to the button, and also start a timer to remove the class 2 seconds later. If the handler sees that "clicked" is already applied to the button, it does nothing.

You could also disable the button; that might be better, as it'd give the user visual indication that the button won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the button on click, and run a timer with a 2-second timeout which re-enables the button when it expires.